# I cannot SSH into a different network that had a different subnet mask

Tags: networking, server, ssh

Cannot ssh into a network with a different subnet configuration

I am having an issue where I cannot ssh from one site to another site where the subnet mask of the local network at each location is different. Location A (where I am located) has a 255.255.248.0 subnet mask, and location B has a 255.255.255.0. The IP ranges are different, 10.1.0.1 vs 10.1.1.1.

When in this config, I cannot ssh into site B from site A. But when I switch site A to a 255.255.255.0 mask, then ssh is able to connect to the remote devices.

Am I doing something wrong here? I need the extra IP addresses at site A, and I don’t have a work around for this. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: What is the connection between Location A and Location B? If it is the Internet, that is, if they are not connected by WiFi or Ethernet cables, then the local IP address won't help. Please [update the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1402089/edit) with Ubuntu version number and type of connection between Location A and B.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, check the following :

1. Check if you can ping your gateway IP.
2. Check if you can ping remote gateway IP. (Since you know the IP and Netmask of remote machine, you can get the gateway IP)
3. Check the firewall rules on both the machines. (Since you have access to both the machines)

If first is possible, then it means that your connection is going to the gateway.

If second is possible, then it means your connection is reaching to remote network and there could be some firewall rules that is affecting the connection.

Answer (score 0):

This is a subnet issue your mask is to broad and it is not getting routed

Range A 10.1.0.1 255.255.248.0 encompasses all addresses from   10.1.0.1 - 10.1.7.254
Range B 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0 is a subset of those addresses

you would need to re-IP the range B to something like 10.1.8.1 so it does not overlap the other range (the other option is to reduce the mask on range A to 255.255.255.0